# Cannot install LibreOffice

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixing Broken Packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30993/fixing-broken-packages)
>   [How to install Libreoffice 3.5.4 in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157991/how-to-install-libreoffice-3-5-4-in-ubuntu-12-04)

What is wrong with Ubuntu repositories?

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-draw but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-filter-mobiledev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-java-common (>= 1:3.5.4~) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed or
                           libreoffice-kde but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Solution is to force version of the package libexttextcat-data to 3.2.0-1ubuntu1 (not to 3.3.1-2~precise1 by default). When I tried to upgrade on version 3.3.1-2~precise1 whole libreoffice is marked to remove.

Comment: Do you have any PPAs added to your system? As LibreOffice is installed by default, you must have removed it at some point.

Comment: when I removed all PPAs, the problem still persist

Comment: Did u run 'sudo apt-get update' after?

Comment: probably same problem: http://www.computersupportforums.com/showthread.php?tid=103452 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12213178#post12213178

Comment: I asked if there were any PPAs installed on the system. Did you just disabled the PPAs from "Software properties" (this doesn't do anything to your installed packages), or did you use ppa-purge?

Comment: Downgrading libexttextcat-data to 3.2.0-1ubuntu1 solved this issue for me. Note, that I had libreoffice's PPA added.

Comment: how to force version of the package libexttextcat-data to 3.2.0-1ubuntu1 (not to 3.3.1-2~precise1 by default)

Answer (score 0):

Go to synaptic package manager (download it if you don't already have it). Try and see if you have any packages installed mentioned in your post (use filter) and then go to the menu select Edit > Fix broken packages.

Alternatively, if you have recently installed Ubuntu using Wubi, I noticed the other day that Quantal Quetzal beta or alpha is currently being used. This is not stable and I had a lot of "broken packages". If that's the case, I don't have the skills to help you further. You'll probably need an alternative arrangement e.g.:
- dual boot (caveat: do your homework extensively before attempting this);
- installing Ubuntu in VirtualBox or VMware.

Comment: OK ... no packages mentioned in the attached output are not installed. So there is nothing to be fixed.

Comment: This is a great tutorial on Youtube about dual-booting. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HANcetKsqc If you follow his instructions to the letter (don't pick "install alongside Windows") , everything will go swimmingly.

Comment: How to download synaptic when having a broken package?!